# How can I access the RGB values of a UIColor?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, core-image

I have an iOS drawing app with buttons that let a user choose colors to draw with. Since my brush uses RGB values but my color constants are UIColors, I need to convert. I tried

```
private var currentButton: UIButton? {
    willSet{
        currentButton?.layer.borderWidth = 0
    }
    didSet{
        currentButton?.layer.borderWidth = 2
        let index = (currentButton?.tag)! - 1
        drawView.brush.blue = colors[index].ciColor.blue //Here is where I get the error
        drawView.brush.green = colors[index].ciColor.green
        drawView.brush.red = colors[index].ciColor.red
    }
}
```

Which I found in another StackOverflow question. However, when I try to get an RGB value in line 8 I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -CIColor not defined for the UIColor UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1; need to first convert colorspace.'
```

It clearly says that I need to convert color space. But `CIColor.colorSpace` is get-only. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `var ciColor: CIColor { get }
Description 
The Core Image color associated with the receiver.
This property throws an exception if the color object was not initialized with a Core Image color.`

Comment: You can use CoreImage.CIColor initializer to create a new color from your UIColor `CoreImage.CIColor(color: colors[index]).blue` with the advantage that it doesn't return an optional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`getRed(_:green:blue:alpha:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621919-getred):

```
var red:   CGFloat = 0
var green: CGFloat = 0
var blue:  CGFloat = 0
var alpha: CGFloat = 0

color.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
```